# pfsense webGui not opening in host os or say, lan ip not accessible in host os

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, virtualbox, pfsense

My host os: ubuntu 16.4
I have installed  pfSense in virtual box.
My Network setting in vb is:

```
adapter1: bridge adapter
name: wlx20...
advance setting: promisc. mode: deny, cable connected: tick
adapter2: internal network , name: intnet
advance setting: same as above.
```

pfSense is installed and I am seeing

```
wan  em0  v4/dhcp 192....
          v6/dhcp  fd..

lan em1 192.168.1.1
```

but when I hit 192.168.1.1 on host browser , I get nothing.
I read the virtual box documentation of network mode , but got nothing helpful.
One answer saying to change to host-only, but it is not done by youtube instructor.
can someone help in describing what may be the issue.
I am a web developer and new to networking .

Can the problem may be with wifi adapter, I am using local wifi receiver and instructor said to use intel wifi adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I fiqured it out.

In virtual box I installed ubuntu also and set it as intenal network.
so pfsense can ping ubuntu and ubuntu can ping pfsense. and webgui is opened.